# IPOptions in scapy3.0.0 and python3.5 is throwing the error

Tags: scapy

My packet:

```
a=IP(src="30.1.1.2",dst="20.1.1.2",options=IPOption('\x83\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'),)
```

I am getting the error:

```
a=bytes(IP(src="30.1.1.2",dst="20.1.1.2",options=IPOption('\‌​x83\x07\x04\x00\x00\‌​x00\x00\x00'),))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/code.py", line 90, in runcode exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/base_classes.p‌​y", line 197, in call
    cls = cls.dispatch_hook(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py‌​", line 161, in dispatch_hook
    opt = pkt[0] & 0x1f
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int' –
```

Comment: Error  >>> a=bytes(IP(src="30.1.1.2",dst="20.1.1.2",options=IPOption('\x83\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'),))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/base_classes.py", line 197, in __call__
    cls =  cls.dispatch_hook(*args, **kargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/scapy/layers/inet.py", line 161, in dispatch_hook
    opt = pkt[0] & 0x1f
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using Python 3, you should use `bytes` instead of `str` for the IP options:

```
a = bytes(IP(src="30.1.1.2", dst="20.1.1.2",
             options=IPOption(b'\x83\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'))
```

Comment: a = IP(src="30.1.1.2", dst="20.1.1.2",
             options=IPOption(b'\x83\x07\x04\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00')    . I believe no need to convert the whole IP packet to bytes. Just converting IPOption to bytes helped me. Thanks Pierre.

Comment: I was just fixing your last line, which starts with `a = bytes(IP([...]))`. Of course, if you want to create an IP Scapy packet, no need for `bytes()`. But if you want to create the bytes that are going to be sent on the network, you need it.